# Providing Uninstall option in custom NuGet packages

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

When creating custom NuGet packages, how do we provide the option for uninstalling a NuGet package, which removes the references/ static files which came as part of the package.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by providing an `uninstall.ps1` script. See [the documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Automatically_Running_PowerShell_Scripts_During_Package_Installation_and_Removal) for further details.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will take a look at it.